# Universal keyboard shortcut for searching/exploring on macOS, similar to Ctrl+E on Windows

Tags: keyboard

This was initially formulated as a question, then I found out the keyboard shortcut of macOS Chrome on its Google search functionality (inputs are never interpreted as website address even if the input is a website address, e.g., asp.net, Chrome will google asp.net instead of visiting it) on its address bar is the same across many macOS apps. I'll answer my own question :)

Anyway here's the question:

Windows has almost universal keyboard shortcut for searching/exploring, it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. It always focus (or pop-up) the input to the app's search bar (if there's any), at least on many apps that I tried

E.g., on Windows, Ctrl+E works the same on Windows Explorer, Microsoft Store, OneNote, Visual Studio Code, Edge, Chrome, Firefox

Is there any similar universal keyboard shortcut in macOS?

Answer (score 2):

On many macOS apps, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> brings up the same <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> functionality from their cousin apps in Windows, e.g., Finder, OneNote, Edge, Chrome, Firefox

One exception is Visual Studio Code for Mac (perhaps all IDEs, text editors), <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> brings up Find-and-Replace functionality instead.

Visual Studio for Mac, brings up Find-and-Replace functionality too. To move the focus on the search bar, press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> instead

On Visual Studio Code (explore actions / files):

- Windows: <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
- macOS: <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> instead of <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Skype for Mac's <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> focuses the input on **People, groups && messages** search bar. Skype for Windows' <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> is not working, perhaps the developers just forgot to implement it.

On Finder, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> merely moves the focus (just like how <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> on Windows apps behaves) on its search bar:

[image]

Finder's <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, has a bit different functionality. I prefer <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> though, it works how I expected it to behave, i.e., it just move the focus on search bar, just like when the search bar is clicked by mouse instead. Finder's <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>:

[image]